# ASP.NET: How to insert blank lines in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, html

I tried to do this to insert a few blank lines in my web page (to separate my text from an image displayed through a script) but it didn't work:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentText" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
...
```

If you have time to explain to me why the series of p's and closing p's didn't work, that'll be great. Otherwise, please just tell me how to insert some space there. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you add a Panel/Div to your page and use CSS to achieve this? For example: `margin-top:100px` or `height:100px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `<br />` which is a line break.

`<p>` are for paragraphs and will separate any text between the opening and closing tag with any other elements, as they are all empty there is no effect.

Investigate `<div>` and `<span>` as there are countless ways to separate elements rather than just a blank line.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<div style="height: 100px"></div>
```

Comment: This I found is faster and more efficient in knowing it will work across ALL browsers

Answer (score 0):

Wouln't it be better to use CSS to achieve what you want?  If you only need a vertical spacing between your text and your image.  I would add a top margin to the image you are inserting throught javascript.

For example:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentText" runat="server">
Your text is here
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<img src="javascript-inserted-image.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="margin-top: 50px;" />
```

In real life, I would be using a CSS class that I would assign to the image instead of applying the margin to the style attribute of the image.

Edited:

Your image would also need to be displayed as a block element (CSS style display: block;) if your the content of your place holder is not a block element like a p, div, blockquote, etc...